# multidatespicker with disabled dates from php variable

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get the holidays from a php function and using them to disable dates for my multidatepicker.

Using jquery multidatespicker from: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

```
//php:

    $holidays = show_holidays($year, $province);
```

which then $holidays echo's as:

```
['01/01/2014','02/17/2014','04/18/2014','05/19/2014,'07/01/2014','08/04/2014','09/01/2014','10/13/2014','12/25/2014','12/26/2014']
```

my js:

```
var holidays = "<?php echo $holidays; ?>";

$('#with-altField').multiDatesPicker({
    addDisabledDates: holidays,
    altField: '#vacationdays',
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

and it doesn't disable the dates...

firebug shows error : `uncaught exception: Missing number at position 0`

Comment: Datepickers usually use a `dd-mm-yyyy` format or that in reverse, but using dashes instead of slashes. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: yes if i use addDisabledDates: ['03/03/2014','03/04/2014'] it works...but thats me manually inputting those dates without the php var

Comment: figured it out.. thanks anyway buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry all, i figured it out... i had to put it in array and remove the [ ] from php var:

changed:

```
var holidays = "<?php echo $holidays; ?>";
```

to

```
var holidays = [ <?php echo $holidays; ?> ];
```

and it works now...